# WPF Grid's Row and Column template manipulation

Tags: wpf, templates, grid, styles

Can we add a Label or whatever Control at the beginning of each Row of a **"Grid"**?

What about at the top of each Column?

Note : I am not talking about **DataGrid**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, It's not possible. `Grid` is a just a layout `Panel`. Though you can write a code to explicitly render `Control` at the  beginning of each row if it's just for one `view` or create a `Custom Control` over `Grid` to make it generic.